# Как реализовать через регулярное выражение проверку по шаблону?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Пользователь вводит адрес https://instagram.com/user-name_1
или имя @user-name_1.

Надо достать только **user-name_1**, но код для "ловли" @user-name_1 почему-то не работает:

```
import re ...

@dp.message_handler(re.findall(r'@\w+'))
async def answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Допустимо ли имя `user-name_1-`? Или в конце не должно быть `-`?

Comment: Ах да, забыл, @.-user-name_12-....  Вот такие комбинации могут быть

Comment: Попробуйте `re.findall(r'@\S+')` или `re.findall(r'@\S+\b')`

Answer (score 0):

```
\w – это символы латиницы, цифры и _
```

Поэтому должно учитываться ещё `-`

Минимальная модификация по Вашему примеру:

```
@[\w-]+
```

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/t4ct8q/1)